# Android : SlidingDrawer for 4 sides library

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I want a sliding drawer that both 4 side : left/right/bottom/up. I see `SlidingMenu library` has this option, but just only two sides : left and right. `MenuDrawer library` can config to 4 sides, but it isn't stable. I try to add 4 listview in each side, but just only one work. `MergeAdapter` doesn't work too.

An ideas for my problem ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to Sliding drawers not Navigation Drawers, then use `android:rotation="angle"` and replace angle with 90, 180, 270 for your purposes. Also apply it to the buttons and layouts to rotate them back to their original state. Remember, this is API level 11 +.